# useEffect run once hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I found this lib https://react-hooks.org/docs/useEffectOnceWhen but I'm confused. Why does it even existed and in what purpose it's used? Isn't I can achieve the same thing using useEffect?

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    }, 3000); // Countdown for 3 sec
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

The hook is `useEffectOnceWhen`, not just `useEffectOnce`. Per the source you linked:

> Runs a callback effect atmost one time when a condition becomes true

[Here's the source code of that hook](https://github.com/imbhargav5/rooks/blob/main/packages/rooks/src/hooks/useEffectOnceWhen.ts):

```
/**
 * useEffectOnceWhen hook
 *
 * It fires a callback once when a condition is true or become true.
 * Fires the callback at most one time.
 *
 * @param callback The callback to fire
 * @param when The condition which needs to be true
 */
function useEffectOnceWhen(callback: () => void, when: boolean = true): void {
  const hasRunOnceRef = useRef(false);
  const callbackRef = useRef(callback);
  useEffect(() => {
    callbackRef.current = callback;
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    if (when && !hasRunOnceRef.current) {
      callbackRef.current();
      hasRunOnceRef.current = true;
    }
  }, [when]);
}
```

As you can see, it does something more advanced than just being called once at the beginning of the hook: it gets called once the condition passed in becomes true for the first time.

Comment: when will I need this? the demo code can be replaced by useEffect

Comment: You're correct, the example in the docs, is a bad example. But there was a button that called `setLoading(true)` and you pressed it, `useEffect(callback, [loading])` would fire again, whereas `useEffectOnceWith(callback, [loading])` would not.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** do the same thing with `useEffect`:

"If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument"

[Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

You can also supply a list of dependencies that trigger the effect running again if they change.

```js
useEffect( () => { doSomething() } , [ifThisChangesRunFuncAgain, orThis, ...] )
```